# Can I keep my iPhone screen off during voice navigation with Apple's Maps app?

Tags: ios, screen, siri, maps, navigation

I have been using voice navigation in Apple's Maps app for iOS 6. I keep the phone in one of my car's cup holders because I am mostly using it in my home area where the maps on the screen aren't necessary. But when each navigation instruction is announced, I see the screen come back on. Sometimes I have my car charger, and sometimes I don't. But regardless of that, the screen coming on when I don't want to or can't look at it is just wrong for this usage scenario. Can I do something to keep the screen off and only use voice navigation?

EDIT: I reported this to Apple through [bugreport.apple.com](http://bugreport.apple.com) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reported a bug to Apple through bugreport.apple.com. It looks like there isn't currently a solution for Apple's Maps app on iOS.

Answer (score 1):

I know this doesn't solve the Apple Maps portion of the question but Google Maps does not behave like this and IMHO is better than Apple maps.